# Open Street Map tile by http request

Tags: http, dictionary

does anyone know how to get a tile from OpenStreetMap by http?
i mean something as static google map , where i can pass in the query string lat lon and zoom , nothing more ...
Sure it is me, but i m losing a lot of time looking for online doc without success  ... maybe someone of you know it on the fly 
Thanks a lot

Comment: You need to look up Web Map Service (WMS).  OSM has WMS servers which will return tiles for you.

Comment: yes it was the appropriate term

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick search returned this page, which might be useful: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tiles@home/APIs